# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Softlayer'

Tags: python, module, pip, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

My softlayer python module is installed but can't be imported

i tried reinstall it ,but still i get the same error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Softlayer'

Hope someone can help

Comment: So you did at first `pip install softlayer` and then tried `python -c "import softlayer"`? Can you show the exact output it is giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to import SoftLayer :

`import SoftLayer` (**Capital L**)

Comment: Yes it was that and something to do with different version of python ,Thanks!